Disabling Bounce Effect in Safari for Vertical Slider While Allowing Page Scroll
How can I disable the 'bounce' effect when scrolling a vertical slider in Safari, while still allowing the rest of the website content to scroll once the last slider item is reached? I tried using overscroll-behavior: none; and overflow: scroll;, which removed the bounce effect but prevented the rest of the content from scrolling when the last slide was reached.
